# Horizontal scrolling side by side <div> tags with set height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a long list of `<div>` tags that I want to stack side by side without any vertical scrolling. I want them to stack horizontally like a slider.

An example is the parent container has a height of 500px, and there are 25 Divs that are 500x500 squares that will sit side by side and scroll horizontally.

I'm trying to create a slider that will sit at the top of a webpage and scroll continuously.

Thanks!

----- EDIT 8/24/15 @2:22pm -----

What I have so far is :

```
      <style type="text/css">
      div.table {display:table; width:100%;}
      div.table-row {display:table-row;}
      div.table-cell {display:table-cell; width:500px; height:500px; margin:0px 5px; background:#1996e6; color:#fff;}
      </style>

      <div class="table"> 
        <div class="table-row"> 
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
          <div class="table-cell">Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: And what do you got so far?

Comment: Sorry, I tried setting things to table cells but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

CSS

```
#container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0bgqgkbL/

Comment: This is super simple! What is the compatibility with old versions of IE?

Comment: It should work well for 8 and up, not sure about 7

Comment: Curious: why not just use an existing slider library?

Comment: Because I already have an existing visualization I want to transition into a horizontal slider.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the size of the container but all you have to do is add the images (captions optional)  http://jsfiddle.net/b7so9870/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rotator > a.arrow.left').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var rotator = $('#rotator .images');
    rotator.children('.imageHolder').first().animate({
      marginLeft: "-=310px"
    }, function() {
      $(this).appendTo(rotator).removeAttr("style");
    });
  });
  $('#rotator > a.arrow.right').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var rotator = $('#rotator .images');
    rotator.children('.imageHolder').last().prependTo(rotator).removeAttr("style").css("margin-left", "-310px").animate({
      marginLeft: "0"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#rotator {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#rotator .images {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -5;
}
#rotator a.arrow {
  width: 18px;
  height: 41px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -50000em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  z-index: 50;
}
#rotator a.arrow.left {
  left: 0; background-image:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/48/arrow_left.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#rotator a.arrow.right {
  right: 0; background-image:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/48/arrow_right.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#rotator .images .imageHolder {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
#rotator .images .imageHolder span {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -3;
}
#rotator .images .imageHolder img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="rotator">
    <a href="#" class="arrow left"></a>
    <div class="images">
      <div class="imageHolder">
        <span>Daisies</span>
        <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="imageHolder">
        <span>Whole choir</span>
        <img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="imageHolder">
        <span>Choir</span>
        <img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara4.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="arrow right">
      <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/48/arrow_right.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is super cool, and you built an actual slider. Thanks! The only problem is the white space next to the images. Is there a way to show part of the image if it won't fit as opposed to simply hiding it?

Comment: the slider is designed to size the images to fit it. my images are not 500x500 but have been sized to fit by the slider

Comment: the white space is where the container ends. it is 500x500. you can center it if you wish

Comment: Gotcha, to clarify the slider would be fit to full width (100%) and a set height of like 500px.

Comment: @DigitalMC absolutely

Comment: how about an accept to make my day? :)

Comment: Ha, well I appreciate the response so much! I'm having a having a problem with full-width container. http://jsfiddle.net/b7so9870/2/

Comment: your images are 500px you can leave the width at 500px. just put margin-left and right auto . the important thing is the images are set to 100% width

Comment: What I'm looking for is the container is full-width and the content scrolls horizontally.  So the content is full width of the page, lets say 1250px, and the content inside of it is 2000px, I want 1250px of the content to show, and the other 750px to be scrollable, or ideally to use the arrows to scroll slowly. I can wire the click event up, no problem. But this is the visualization. Make sense?

Comment: That's not what the question asked for

Comment: I'm in France where its 10 pm. Accept and ask a new question. I'll look at it tomorrow

Comment: It's exactly what I asked for. I wanted a horizontally scrolling slider. Sorry I can't accept. I genuinely appreciate the work though.